# Class does not implement “Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface”

Tags: symfony

I create a form to modify my data, but when I want to access my form, I get this error :

> Could not load type "App\Entity\Clients": class does not implement
>   "Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface".

### ClientsEntity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ClientsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_clients")
 */
class Clients
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

### ClientType :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Clients;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
          $builder
              ->add('name', null, array(
                  'label'    => 'Domaine du client',
                  'required' => true,
              ))
          ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Clients::class,
            'name' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

### ClientsController :

```
   /**
     * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="support_admin_client_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Clients $clients): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(ClientType::class, $clients);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('support_admin_client_index', [
                'id' => $clients->getId(),
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('admin/ticketing/client/edit.html.twig', [
            'clients' => $clients,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

My form implements AbstractType so I do not see where my error comes from.
Do you know where this message comes from?

Comment: Where do you use ClientType? I think error comes from there. Instead of calling ClientType::class, you call Clients::class

Comment: @JessGabriel I modify my post, I use ClientType in my controller

Comment: can you include the information to what row of the code the error is pointing to - and the template (twig) file if the error originates from there?

Comment: It's ok I found, the twig call a controller that I forgot to delete

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Now ask yourself if your Clients entity really holds multiple clients.  If not, rename to Client and save yourself some future head scratching.  Keep the database table name plural as a table holds a collection of records but most entities are singular.

Comment: @Cerad. The first point is good and valid (renaming the entity to Client as it probably represents a singular client) - but giving advice that table names should be plural sounds more like advocating your personal preference about the topic instead of it being a convention / "right way" to go about it. I would advice to pick either one (plural/singular) he/she considers to be more logical and just be consistent with that. And yes - I personally use singular table names as I consider that to be more logical :)

Comment: @SkroS2 Ce serai bien de partager la solution avec quelques détails !